# Xpath: Select text and subchild node

Tags: java, xml, xpath, sax, xpath-2.0

Having an XML

```
<node>Text1<subnode/>text2</node>
```

How do I select whole substring inside `<node>` tag?

Something like this:

```
Text1<subnode/>text2
```

Writing xpath as: `./node/text()` returns null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`./node/node()` returns a sequence of three nodes:

- A text node whose string value is "Text1"
- An element node whose name is "subnode"
- A text node whose string value is "text2"

If you want the string `"Text1<subnode/>text2"` then that involves serializing the element node. XPath cannot see the original lexical XML, only a tree of nodes, so if you want lexical XML then you have to reconstruct it: this process is called serialization. To do serialization from within XPath you will need XPath 3.0, which has a `serialize()` function that converts a node tree into a string.